# css3 text-shadow in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, css3pie, css

Is there an easy way to have css3 `text-shadow`'s working in IE9?  At least a single text shadow would be great.  I guess ideally IE8 is supported as well.  I'm hoping there's a simple jquery plugin or .htc file which just looks at text-shadow css property of an element and implements it for IE9.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Yes, but not how you would imagine. According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=text-shadow) (a very good resource) there is no support and no polyfill available for adding `text-shadow` support to IE9. However, **IE has their own proprietary text shadow ([detailed here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms673539%28VS.85%29.aspx)).**

Example implementation, taken from their website (works in IE5.5 through IE9):

```
p.shadow { 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#0000FF,direction=45);
}
```

For cross-browser compatibility and future-proofing of code, remember to also use the CSS3 standard `text-shadow` property ([detailed here](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/text-shadow)). This is especially important considering that IE10 has officially announced their intent to [drop support for legacy dx filters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/06/04/legacy-dx-filters-removed-from-ie10-release-preview.aspx). Going forward, IE10+ will only support the CSS3 standard `text-shadow`.

Comment: When you say filters won't work in IE10, does that mean they won't even work if I change the browser mode to IE9? Because none of these filters are working for me in IE10 with browser mode IE9. Should I just assume that they would work on a real IE9 browser?

Comment: @andrewtweber might make sense to verify this in browserstack.com -- but yeah, that sounds like IE10 engine dropped it completely.  In IE9, choosing IE7 mode also has bizzare quirks like that (i.e. ie7 doesn't like console.log() but ie9 handles it alright in ie7 mode)

Comment: I'm using IE11 to simulate older browsers. Is it worth mentioning that the function to render these filters is [deactivated](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/06/04/legacy-dx-filters-removed-from-ie10-release-preview.aspx) by default?

Answer (score 26):

As IE9 does not support CSS3 `text-shadow`, I would just use the filter property for IE instead. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/dmM2S/

```
text-shadow:1px 1px 1px red; /* CSS3 */
```

can be replaced with

```
filter: Shadow(Color=red, Direction=130, Strength=1); /* IE Proprietary Filter*/
```

You can get the results to be very similar.

Comment: filter: Shadow(Color=red, Direction=130, Strength=1); /* IE Proprietary Filter*/ makes it even worse than having no text-shadow at all.

Comment: filter: glow(color=black, strength=1) seems to give a better effect

Comment: Be careful with specifying `filter: Shadow` and `text-shadow` at the same time, like in your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmM2S/). After all, IE10 will support `text-shadow` and I assume that it also supports `filter: Shadow`. The result of applying both properties could be interesting.

Comment: @feklee: IE10 dropped support for filters in an effort to become more standards compliant: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/12/07/moving-to-standards-based-web-graphics-in-ie10.aspx. If you check the fiddle in IE10 you will see that only the CSS3 `text-shadow` works.

Answer (score 13):

Try [CSS Generator](http://css3generator.com).

You can choose values and see the results online. Then you get the code in the clipboard.
This is one example of generated code:

```
text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #a8aaad;
filter: dropshadow(color=#a8aaad, offx=1, offy=1);
```

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for a cross-browser text-stroke solution that works when overlaid on background images. think I have a solution for this that doesn't involve extra mark-up, js and works in IE7-9 (I haven't tested 6), and doesn't cause aliasing problems.

This is a combination of using CSS3 text-shadow, which has good support except IE (http://caniuse.com/#search=text-shadow), then using a combination of filters for IE.  CSS3 text-stroke support is poor at the moment.

**IE Filters**

The glow filter (http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-text-shadow-ie/) looks terrible, so I didn't use that.

[David Hewitt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567677/simulating-text-stroke-in-internet-explorer/11538482#11538482) involved adding dropshadow filters in a combination of directions. ClearType is then removed unfortunately so we end up with badly aliased text.

I then combined some of the elements suggested on [useragentman](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/09/02/how-to-make-cleartype-font-face-fonts-and-css-visual-filters-play-nicely-together/) with the dropshadow filters.

**Putting it together**

This example would be black text with a white stroke. I'm using conditional html classes by the way to target IE (http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/).

```
#myelement {
    color: #000000;
    text-shadow:
    -1px -1px 0 #ffffff,  
    1px -1px 0 #ffffff,
    -1px 1px 0 #ffffff,
    1px 1px 0 #ffffff;
}

html.ie7 #myelement,
html.ie8 #myelement,
html.ie9 #myelement {
    background-color: white;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(color='white') progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(color=#ffffff,offX=1,offY=1) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(color=#ffffff,offX=-1,offY=1) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(color=#ffffff,offX=1,offY=-1) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(color=#ffffff,offX=-1,offY=-1);
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: +1 This is a good approach because it prevents future IE versions (which may support text-shadow) from applying both text-shadow AND the filter to the same text.

Comment: @Moses: in fact, in this case it's unnecessary, since the version of IE that introduced `text-shadow` (IE10) was also the same version that dropped support for the old `filter` styles, so they can never clash. (however, for other styles it is necessary -- eg `transform` is supported in IE9, and can thus clash with `filter` styles doing the same thing, with messy results)

Comment: The best looking solution I've found! :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried out the filters referenced above and strongly disliked the effect it created. I also didn't want to use any plugins since they'd slow down loading time for what seems like such a basic effect.

In my case I was looking for a text shadow with a 0px blur, which means the shadow is an exact replica of the text but just offset and behind. This effect can be easily recreated with jquery.

```
<script>
    var shadowText = $(".ie9 .normalText").html();  
    $(".ie9 .normalText").before('<div class="shadow">' + shadowText + '</div>');
</script>
<style>
    .ie9 .shadow { position: relative; top: 2px; left: -3px; }
</style>
```

This will create an identical effect to the css3 text-shadow below.

```
    text-shadow: -3px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
```

here's a working example (see the large white text over the main banner image) http://www.cb.restaurantconnectinc.com/

Answer (score 0):

The answer of *crdunst* is pretty neat and the best looking answer I've found but there's no explanation on how to use and the code is bigger than needed.

The only code you need:

```
#element {
    background-color: #cacbcf;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
    filter: chroma(color=#cacbcf) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(color=#60000000, offX=2, offY=2);
}
```

First you **MUST** specify a `background-color` - if your element should be transparent just copy the background-color of the parent or let it inherit. The color at the chroma-filter must match the background-color to fix those artifacts around the text (but here you must copy the color, you can't write `inherit`). Note that I haven't shortened the *dropshadow-filter* - it works but the shadows are then cut to the element dimensions (noticeable with big shadows; try to set the offsets to atleast 4).

**TIP:** If you want to use colors with transparency (alpha-channel) write in a **#AARRGGBB notation**, where AA stands for a hexadezimal value of the opacity - from 01 to FE, because FF and ironically also 00 means no transparency and is therefore useless.. ^^ Just go a little lower than in the rgba notation because the shadows aren't soft and the same alpha value would appear darker then. ;)

A nice snippet to convert the alpha value for IE (JavaScript, just paste into the console):

```
var number = 0.5; //alpha value from the rgba() notation
("0"+(Math.round(0.75 * number * 255).toString(16))).slice(-2);
```

**ISSUES:** The text/font behaves like an image after the shadow is applied; it gets pixelated and blurry after you zoom in... But that's IE's issue, not mine.


Live demo of the shadow here: http://jsfiddle.net/12khvfru/2/