# IE9 text shadow - filter: glow, chroma and shadow

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to place shadow behind text in IE9. Because IE sucks I already used filter glow to accomplish the effect in IE7 and 8.

I did some research and found out that IE9 doesn't support filter glow anymore and also does not support CSS3 property text-shadow (WHY MS? WHY?!).

So I played around with the ms filter's shadow and dropshadow but that doesnt fix anything. Also everything I tried lead to the black background color (see screenshot).

CSS I'm using

```
 text-shadow: 0 0 0.6em #000, 0 0 0.6em #000;
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.glow(color=#606060,strength=2);
 background-color:transparent;
```

and a rendering screenshot

[image]

Note: The css above is being applied to an div containing text.

The solution I'm looking for preferably is css-only but if js is necessary, than thats the way it is.

ps. I have to mention this, I cant stop thinking about some IE9 announcement poster saying "Sorry developers, but we will make it up to you", I falsely hoped IE would stop raping my time.

Comment: according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905658/css3-text-shadow-in-ie9 `Shadow` should work somehow...

Answer (score 1):

Use this jquery plugin for a perfect text shadow in all browsers...

https://github.com/heygrady/textshadow

Thank you