# IE8 Anchor Text Shadow on Hover

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, jsfiddle

I am in ASP.NET, but the problem is completely HTML related. I have this following code:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" CssClass="message-box">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LogoutLinkButton" runat="server">Logout</asp:LinkButton>
</asp:Panel>
```

The equivalent HTML is:

```
<div class="message-box">
    <a href="#">Logout</a>
</div>
```

And the CSS classes are:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit; 
}

.message-box {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: right;  
}

.message-box a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline; 
    text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em black;
}
```

The demonstration can be found in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XWpAx/).

This text-shadow of the anchor text is not working in IE8/ IE9. How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905658/css3-text-shadow-in-ie9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

text-shadow is a css3 property. so you can not user it in IE.
But you can user filter:shadow to meet you requirement

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried to use .message-box a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline; 
 text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em black;
 filter: shadow(color=#000000,direction=135,strength=5);
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#000000,direction=135,strength=5)";
} but it is not working.

Comment: On a side note, the MDN is often a good source for browser compatability, e.g. [text-shadow browser support on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-shadow#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @Tapas The element must have _layout_ for the filter to work.