# internet explorer text-shadow + hover

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, css

I am trying to make a page that 'unblurs' (removes the text shadow) on hover.

This works in all browsers except for IE: http://mmhudson.com/brett.html

It doesn't work because I am setting the color to 'transparent' when the element is not being hovered on and the IE filter 'blur' inherits that so the text shadow is also transparent.

How can I make the filter not inherit that or make it so that only the shadow is invisible?

I am currently using a plugin, but I could use regular css if that is preferable.

http://jsfiddle.net/PaDwt/

Note the html if IE block

I only need support for IE8 and IE9, but IE7 and earlier would be good too.

Comment: The problem is not that it is inheriting the transparent color, it's that IE doesn't support text-shadow at all. Use this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905658/css3-text-shadow-in-ie9

Comment: useless comment ^ if you had looked at my jsfiddle or page source you would have seen I had already figured that much out and that I am clearly not asking how to use text shadow in IE

Comment: updated my answer. Take a look and let me know if that's the end result your are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not that it is inheriting the transparent color, it's that IE doesn't support text-shadow at all.

Use this stackoverflow.com/questions/6905658/css3-text-shadow-in-ie9

```
p.shadow { 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#0000FF,direction=45);
}
```

-----------EDIT--------------

Is this what you're looking for?
http://jsfiddle.net/PaDwt/4/

-CSS

```
#paragraphs p{
  /*the width needs to be a set value, not a percentage*/
  width: 600px;
  /*blur all paragraphs*/
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #666666;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=3);
}
```

-JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($.browser.msie) $("#paragraphs p").css("color", "black");
  $("#paragraphs p").mouseover(function(){
    var thisP = this;
    if($.browser.msie)
    {
      $("#paragraphs p").css({
        filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=3)"
      });
    }
    else{
      $("#paragraphs p").css({
        color:"transparent",
        textShadow:"0 0 2px #666",
      });
    }
    $(thisP).css({
      color:"#000",
      textShadow:"none",
      filter:"none"
    })
  });
  $("#paragraphs p").mouseout(function(){
    if($.browser.msie)
    {
      $("#paragraphs p").css({ 
        filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=3)"
      });
    }
    else
    {
      $("#paragraphs p").css({
        color:"transparent",
        textShadow:"0 0 2px #666"
      });
    }
  });
});​
```

This works for me in IE9.

Comment: If you could delete this please. People will think it is a possible solution and it is not. Also if that downvote was you, please remove it unless you have a good reason to keep it

Answer (score 0):

Look this: [CSS Blurred text shadow in IE part I](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/04/23/css-blurred-text-shadow-in-ie-part-i/)

Comment: already done.. that's not my issue. I can blur the text fine, the issue is that the blur filter inherits the color property i set rather than using the color parameter I specified.