# Text-shadow not working in IE9, using css?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [css3 text-shadow in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905658/css3-text-shadow-in-ie9)

I am using text-shadow style, but its not working in ie9, please tell me suggestion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905658/css3-text-shadow-in-ie9

Answer (score 1):

IE9 doesn't support `text-shadow` [see here](http://caniuse.com/#search=text-shadow) - use something like

```
filter: Shadow(Color=black, Direction=100, Strength=1);
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Tp9Mr/)