# IE adding shadow to drop menu sub items

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have just been testing a website in IE and everything works fine apart from the drop down menu in IE is adding shadows to the text. It looks fine in Chrome and firefox, just not working in IE.

address is: www.rbc.org.uk

Any ideas?

Comment: How would you like us to troubleshoot your problem with absolutely no code or fiddle to go by ?

Comment: Could you provide some CSS, HTML? or a an example using Fiddle.

Comment: sorry about that, the address is www.rbc.org.uk. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE 8,9 does not support `text-shadow` like other standard browsers. You should do this by:
[**Static Filters**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms673539%28VS.85%29.aspx)

example:

```
.shadow { 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#0000FF,direction=45);
}
```

For more information i strongly recommend you to google and check out this question:
[**css3 text-shadow in IE9**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905658/css3-text-shadow-in-ie9)

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more clear. I don't want to add a shadow, I want to remove it. There is no shadow in Chrome but there is in IE.

Comment: @user1932603 It's better to show your menu css code. but try to find your menu css class that has `filter:` and remove it.