# CSS - How can I make a font readable over any color?

Tags: html, css, fonts

Assuming I have a set font color that I must maintain, and that it overlays content that can be of any color, how can I make sure the font is readable no matter what it's overlaying?

Here is a jsFiddle to demonstrate the effect I am trying to describe.
http://jsfiddle.net/4AUDr/

```
#overlay 
{
    position: relative;
    top: -150px;
    color: #860101;
}
```

Meme captions utilize white text with a black outline to make it readable over any hypothetical meme image, however I don't think there is a cross-browser compatible CSS only method of achieving that, and it would potentially look quite horrible with smaller fonts.

What solutions are there to this problem?

Comment: Your code? What have you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I don't know a good solution.

Comment: fixed the jsFiddle. Had to attach code.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can experiment with `text-shadow` property ([MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow)), for instance:

```
text-shadow: white 0px 0px 10px;
```

([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4AUDr/1/))

It's supported in IE10. For IE9, you can use proprietary Internet Explorer filters as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6905713/782609).

Comment: Good answer!  White text with a black border tends to work pretty well. http://jsfiddle.net/4AUDr/49/

Answer (score 39):

While text-shadow is nice, it doesn't actually give the result you want. A shadow is a shadow and what you need to have for most readable text is a "text border". Unfortunately. there is no such thing as text-border in css, but we can make one !

I am surprised by how much unpopular multiple shadows are. This is a case where by multiple shadows you can do miracles :

**CSS**

```
p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-shadow:
        0.07em 0 black,
        0 0.07em black,
        -0.07em 0 black,
        0 -0.07em black;
}
```

This style will simply add a thin shadow (as thin as 7% of your actual font-size) around your text (up, down, left, right).

But are four shadows enough ? Maybe you can get a better result with eight ? It looks like the answer is yes, makes sense to me, but it could also be that we are overkilling things here. Note that in this case I also decreased each shadow's size :

**CSS**

```
p.with-eight {
    text-shadow:
        0.05em 0 black,
        0 0.05em black,
        -0.05em 0 black,
        0 -0.05em black,
        -0.05em -0.05em black,
        -0.05em 0.05em black,
        0.05em -0.05em black,
        0.05em 0.05em black;
}
```

Then in this markup in a colourful background you have a nicely readable text:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>This text is readable on any background.</p>
    <p class="with-eight">This text is using eight text-shadows.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/dimitriadisg/agnfz7qt/)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the css3 property `text-shadow`

Warning: Browser compatibility problems (IE9 no support)

http://caniuse.com/css-textshadow

a simple example:

`.shadow {text-shadow: 4px 4px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);}`

http://jsfiddle.net/H4JtR/

If you use white shadow over black fonts, or vice-versa, your text will be readable no matter what is overlaying.

Another option is to use a `background-color` with transparency (you may want to apply this to an inline element like a `span` or a `p` instead of a `div` because `background-color` is going to apply to the whole div area even where there is no text)

`background: rgba(33, 33, 33, .9);`

http://jsfiddle.net/LSRkE/

Just use a transparency that contrasts with your font color. Then you can lower the `alpha-channel` value so the image from the background will be visible enough.

Related answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5135033/953684

Comment: While it is a very good solution, I am almost certain that my employer will not allow it because it will conflict with the style of the website.

Comment: @Nikzilla please check updated answer for antoher option

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this CSS was not around at the time this question was answered, but you can use **stroke** to add a nice border around text. Like this:

```
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
-webkit-text-stroke-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
```