# Text-Shadow in IE

Tags: html, css

I found a Stackoverflow article on creating text shadows in IE: [StackQuestion](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/css/cross-browser-drop-shadows)
Now I tried all of the 'filter' solutions in there, and in IE9, the text renders horrible(although the shadow shadow shows, the text pixelates heavily...).

Does anyone know of a proper text-shadow technique for IE? Even if it is just for IE9...

Thank You

Comment: possible duplicate of [css3 text-shadow in IE9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905658/css3-text-shadow-in-ie9)

Comment: Thanks, but it still renders horrible. I guess I'll just have to wait for IE10.

Comment: You should set up a public test-case to get more help. Anybody else is able to have text-shadows even in IE7, so there must be some solution…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this site out: http://css3pie.com/

It's a plugin that enables you to use CSS3 in IE6-9

Comment: Unless I'm going mad and missed something obvious, CSS3PIE supports `box-shadow` but not `text-shadow` (actually [this post seems to confirm that text-shadow isn't supported](http://css3pie.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1135) )

Comment: I know that it is supported in IE8 and 9, though it is a bit rough

Answer (score 1):

You *can* get text-shadow effects in Internet Explorer, taming IE's crunky filter shadow effects, forcing them to look okay and stop pixelating the text. Use the IE Chroma filter:

- Set a background colour that is close to, but not the same as, your shadow colour - e.g. for black shadows, a dark grey, for white glows, a light grey
- (set the background colour in a stylesheet or style rule inside an IE-only class or conditional comment, to not wreck your design in every other browser!)
- Precede your IE filter CSS rule with a Chroma filter set to the same colour as the background fill
- It looks (almost) quite good!

### [jsfiddle examples](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2tYF/12/) (load in IE8, IE9)

...or if you don't have easy access to IE8/9, here's a screenshot from that fiddle in IE9 IE8 mode. Notice the difference between the horrible, artifact-ridden, pixelated mess that is IE's default filter, against the quite crisp, normal-looking Chroma filter equivalents.

[image]

CSS code examples. Note how you've got a Chroma filter then another filter, all on one line, in quotes against one `-ms-filter` - and how the Chroma colour matches the background colour *precisely*, and how the Chroma colour compliments (but doesn't match) the main effect colour:

```
.chroma-glow {
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(Color=#dfdfdf)progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Glow(color=ffffff,strength=4)";
}
.chroma-shadow {
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(Color=#dfdfdf)progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(direction=135,strength=2,color=ffffff)";
}
```

---

Some requirements (learned the hard way...)

- Elements must be `block` or `inline-block`, can't be `inline`.
- Filters fail to apply to any children that are `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;`

  - (they work if applied directly to `position: absolute;` or `position: relative; elements)
- If you're adding the filters dynamically, e.g. with jQuery like `$elem.css('filter','progid...');`, it seems like the background colour must be applied directly to the element with the filter for the chroma to work. A couple of tips:

  - Have the effect colour, applied background colour, and chroma colour all identical
  - Since you'll want this background colour only in IE, use feature detection or IE detection.

Answer (score 0):

```
#element {  
    filter: glow(color=black,strength=5);  
}
```