# -webkit-text-stroke for Explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the following CSS:

`-webkit-text-stroke: 0.04em; white; -webkit-text-fill-color: white; text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);`

`-webkit-text-stroke: 0.04em; white;` works well in Firefox, Safari, and Chrome. But it's not compatible with Explorer. How can I make it work in Explorer too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulating text-stroke in Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567677/simulating-text-stroke-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: As I am using **-webkit-text-stroke** to fatten the letters, and **text-shadow** to create a darker area around the text (for clarity of the letters when placed over a photo) it only leave two others, but these don't work in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

It's not natively supported in IE, here's the [CanIUse browser support table](http://caniuse.com/#search=text-stroke). It also has poor support in Edge. However, you can use a filter to achieve the same effect.

Here is a link to [a fiddle of it working](http://jsfiddle.net/kovalchik/yJff9/). Credit to the author of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4567701/7236046) where it is due as well.

*An example of the CSS required...*

```
.myClass {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=-1, OffY=-1, Color=#000000)progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=-1, OffY=1, Color=#000000)progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=-1, OffY=0, Color=#000000)progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=1, OffY=-1, Color=#000000)progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=1, OffY=1, Color=#000000)progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=1, OffY=0, Color=#000000)progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=0, OffY=-1, Color=#000000)progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=0, OffY=1, Color=#000000)";
}
```

Comment: As I am using **-webkit-text-stroke** to fatten the letters, and **text-shadow** to create a darker area around the text (for clarity of the letters when placed over a photo) it only leave two others, but these don't work in Safari.

Comment: **-webkit-text-stroke** should work in Safari as long as it has the prefix.

Comment: **-webkit-text-stroke** works in Safari but not in IE

Comment: Yes, but have you tried using the -ms-filter example above?

Comment: **-ms-filter** is not working for Safari. I have to check later if it works for IE. So if it does, I'll need **-ms-filter** and **-webkit-text-stroke** both for Safari and IE I guess (?)

Comment: "Glow, but it creates a blurry glow, not a solid outline."